# Pine script multi expression switch

Tags: pine-script

How do I get multi expressions to work in a Pine Script switch? Something like this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test switch", overlay = true)

if barstate.islast
    a = 2
    switch a
        1 or 2 =>
            label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(a))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi expressions is not supported.

You need to use `if` blocks instead.

```
if barstate.islast
    a = 2
    
    if ((a == 1) or (a == 2))
        label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(a))
```